# Characterization of the class On

Tags: set-theory

If $A$ is a transitive, wellfounded and $\in$- connected class that is not a set, then A=On. Could Someone help  me with the proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

First show that $A$ contains only ordinals. (It is transitive and $\in$-connected.)

Then suppose that $A \subsetneq \operatorname{On}$ and let $\alpha := \min \left( \operatorname{On} \setminus A \right)$. Show that $A \subseteq \alpha$ is a set and derive the desired contradiction. (Again this uses that $A$ is transitive and $\in$-connected.)

Comment: Could you give some more details for the first part?

Comment: Let $x \in A$ be minimal such that it isn't an ordinal. Then $x$ contains only ordinals and hence there is some ordinal $\alpha < \sup x$ such that $\alpha \not \in x$. By the minimality of $x$ we have $\alpha \in A$. But, since $A$ is $\in$-connected we must have $\alpha \in x$ or $x \in \alpha$ or $x = \alpha$. All these options are absurd. Contradiction!

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan your answer is very helpfull for me! Could you just help me with arguing that A $\subseteq \alpha $  is a set ?

Comment: Sure. Since $A$ is a class, there is some $\mathcal{L}_{\in}$-formula $\phi$ and some parameter $p$ such that $A = \{ x \mid \phi(x,p)\}$. Now, if $A \subseteq \alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ (or just a set), then $A = \{ x \in \alpha \mid \phi(x, p) \}$ is a set (by comprehension). Contradiction!

Comment: Thank you Stefan ! Can you help me with the rest of the proof i am still not so sure what to do (this all very new to me) ??

Comment: You now only need to see that $A \subseteq \alpha$. Suppose not. Let $\beta = \min A \setminus \alpha$. Then, by choice of $\alpha$, $\beta \noteq \alpha$. Hence $\alpha \in \beta \in A$. Since $A$ is transitive we now have $\alpha \in A$. Contradiction!

Comment: Got it ! Thank you so much for your patience !!!

Comment: You're most welcome!